# Damping in a stick-slip model

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, oscillators

Usually the spring/block stick-slip models also include a damper. eg:

https://nptel.ac.in/courses/112102015/10

I don't really understand the purpose of the damper. What does it represent? 
Also, how does it influence the critical velocity of the system? 
ps: I'm interested in stick-slip between solid metals (due to shearing).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during the slip phase of stick-and-slip friction, the two surfaces are rubbing against each other, exerting forces in opposition to the direction of relative movement and thereby performing work on each other. The energy expended this way leaves the system, and for purposes of modeling the system, a damper or dissipative element is added that represents that loss.

Comment: Now I see. This had been my original guess, but I was so unsure about it. Thank you Niels!